# Why text inserted in listcontrol in mfc showing truncating text? listcontrol is re sizable?

Tags: c++, mfc, listcontrol

I have a dialog box and list control on it.
I have added a huge string in the list control using `insertitem`.

```
 m_WSDLParamList.InsertItem(LVIF_TEXT | LVIF_PARAM, i, str, 0, 0, 0, NULL); 
// str is very huge.
```

Now, I got back the string using

```
CString str = m_WSDLParamList.GetItemText(5,0);
```

(i.e. whatever I put I got it as it is.)

But, in display I see the string truncated. Why is that?

> Note : my dialog box is re-sizable , so is `listcontrol`.

code -

mylist.EnableToolTips(TRUE);
    mylist.SetExtendedStyle(LVS_EX_INFOTIP | mylist.GetExtendedStyle());
    mylist.InsertColumn(0, L"suri", LVCFMT_LEFT, 100);

```
CString str1 = L"nonNegativeInteger GetVehicleOwnerHolderByRegNumAndDateResponse.GetVehicleOwnerHolderByRegNumAndDateResult[optional].GetVehicleOwnerHolderByRegNumAndDateResultType.VHOwnerHolderResponse.VHOwnerHolderResponseType.Body.VehicleCountries.VehicleCountriesType.VehicleCountry[1, unbound].VehicleCountryType.VehCountryReplies.VehCountryRepliesType.VehCountryReply[1, unbound].Messages[optional].Message[1, unbound].MessageType.MessageCode"; 
for (int i = 0; i < 20 ; i++) {
    mylist.InsertItem(LVIF_TEXT | LVIF_PARAM, i, str1, 0, 0, 0, NULL);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please show the code that defines the columns for the header control of the CListCtrl.

Comment: Some pictures would help.

Comment: Because I miss more information I try to guess:

You have list control in report mode. You inserted a column that is limited in width. So all items are truncated to the width of the column in the list control.

Comment: please see the the attached pictures

Answer (score 1):

Use [LVM_SETCOLUMNWIDTH](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/bb761163%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to define the width you want.

Comment: my list box is auto resizebale columns. if i resize column width , still it shows the trucation. i read following link and found that it is mfc limitation http://microsoft.public.vc.mfc.narkive.com/69A1zQtc/how-to-show-more-than-255-chars-as-item-in-clistctrl-urgent-plz

Comment: No. I can not agree to that. The posting is about Report mode. As far as I see you don't have Report mode enabled.